# Function Composed by successions

Tags: convergence-divergence, function-and-relation-composition

Assume that $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and so is defined the succession of function $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, which converges at $f$.

What can we say about the succession $\phi\circ f$?

Let me know if there's someone who can help me! thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know what to do, to be honest..

Comment: It's VERY hard to help you, if you don't show your efforts and/or attempts (see also your previous questions...)